# How to access and edit Startup applications in Elementary OS Freya beta 2?

Tags: startup, elementary-os

The list accessible in Settings>Applications>Startup is empty by default:

[image]

[Here](http://howtoelementaryos.org/how-to-display-hidden-auto-start-entries-in-elementary-os) and in other places I found the idea that running this command should solve it:

```
sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop
```

But it does not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The application to start is called `gnome-session-properties` (part of `gnome-session-bin`). There the list can be edited.

[image]

Any changes there will then appear in the other list accessible from Settings>Applications>Startup; thus, the latter is limited only to reverting to defaults.

[image]

In order to access that in the Panel Launcher (Applications), I have created a .desktop file inspired by the other such files that can be found in `usr/share/applications` with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=StartupApps
Comment=View apps starting with the system
GenericName=StartupApps
Icon=preferences-system
Terminal=false
Categories=Gnome;Gtk;System;
Exec=gnome-session-properties
```

So that it now can be found when searched or under Applications>System Tools

[image]

Comment: gnome-session-properties is no longer available in the repositories. Was it renamed to something else?

Comment: @Sarvex - you should ask a specific question on https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/. I am not using elementary at this time.